# Calling https version of TYPO3: content (css, js, ..) is blocked because link to http version

Tags: https, typo3

In Chrome I get the following error messages in the console

> [blocked] The page at https://domain.com/home.html ran insecure
>   content from
>   http://domain.com/typo3temp/stylesheet_09c1ef800c.css?1345207892.

if I call https://domain.com. The user gets a page without stylesheets and images. What can I do against this?

The files are included like `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>` but I don't want to define the domain.

Should I completely switch to https by setting the base URL with https? Which other possibilites do I have?

Comment: If your proposal solved the question, please consider to either delete the whole question or add your edit as an answer. And BTW: you can specify your assets like `<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.foo.com/js/lib/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>`, which will use the current protocol the browser uses.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't want use `foo.com` because if at some time the URL changes I'd have to change everything again. Perhaps one could use a variable `{$thisdomain}` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
config {
        baseURL = https://domain.com
}
```

and adapted all links which had a http in the beginning (otherwise the slider stopped working because Chrome didn't load the other ressources ...). Seems to work now.